# If variables are not defined, Are there any default values assigned to them?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a code to pop-up message as "Goal Completed" if target cell has value greater than 80.

But If I type variables in cells, The message is popping up. why? and how to solve it?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
If Target.Value > 80 Then MsgBox "Goal Completed"
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `If Val(Target.Value) > 80 Then MsgBox "Goal Completed"`

Answer (score 1):

It is always best to turn *Tools, Options. Require Variable Declaration* ON. If not, VBA will declare the variable on first use and if you have made a typo in the name, a new variable is created and you can have a bad time finding the error, for exmple `alSets` and `a1Sets`.

As for your question: strings are initialized to empty, integers to 0 etcetera. For tour specific behavior, use your debugger to check what is in the variable and to check what happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address <> "$B$2" Then _
        Exit Sub

    If IsError(Target.Value) Then _
        Exit Sub

    If Target.Value = "" Then _
        Exit Sub

    If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then _
        Exit Sub

    If Target.Value > 80 Then
        MsgBox "Goal Completed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that the value is actually a number, you can use something like `IsNumeric()` but you can get a false positive so I would use pattern matching for this kind of thing:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
    If Target.Value Like Application.Rept("[0-9]", Len(Target.Value)) Then
        If Target.Value > 80 Then MsgBox "Goal Completed"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Note I've also used the `Worksheet_Change` event instead which is more suited to this kind of requirement.